# make a connection from my program to database

Tags: java

I am new to programming and i am trying to make a connection from my program to database but when i make the code,error occurred on line 34 (package con.msql.jdbc does not exit).Can u tell me why??help me

code :

```
package Absensi_PEgawai;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class koneksi {
    private static Connection koneksi;

    public static Connection getKoneksi()
    {
        //cek koneksi
        if(koneksi == null)
        {
            try
            {
                String url;
                url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbabsensipegawai";
                String user = "root";
                String password = "pk12basketboy";

      line34 --> **DriverManager.registerDriver(new con.mysql.jdbc.Driver());**
                 koneksi = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
            }catch(SQLException t)
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error Membuat Koneksi");
                    }
        }    

        return koneksi;
    }

    static Object getConnection()
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not Yet Implemented");
    }
```

}

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Looks like a typo. "con" should be "com"

Comment: Is con.mysql a typo? for com.mysql?

Answer (score 0):

You must have forgotten to add the database driver to the CLASSPATH. If you are under Eclipse, go to the **Build path** menu and add your driver, otherwise refer to the billion posts on the internet that explain how to add a class to the CLASSPATH for any system.